# Using Eclipse-CDT

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I am already using eclipse for JAVA and I wanted to install eclipse-CDT for C/C++ program development. To install eclipse-CDT I typed

sudo apt-get install eclipse-cdt

in the terminal and it installed correctly. But when I launch eclipse again and go to file->new, I don't see any provision for creating a C/C++ project. Kindly help

Answer (score 0):

You can install CDT as follows:

1. Download zip file directly from [here](http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/downloads.php) and use CDT by unzipping it.
2. Using update site.

   - Go to Help → Install New Software
   - Select Copy `p2 software repository` path for your eclipse release from the above link
   - Paste this link in **Work with** text box and then select all the features install CDT.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use eclipse gui installer. I never had a problems with cdt. You can to download it from official eclipse website.