# Using eclipse with Java and C

Tags: java, c, eclipse

I mostly use Java for programming and I used Eclipse as an (IDE). Now, I would like to  add CDT to use c to program network sockets. I followed the steps [here](https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/EclipseCpp_HowTo.html)

i.e., first I downloaded Xcode, then added the plug in  "C/C++ Development Tools"

I don't know how to create a c project, when I clicked on  File > New > Project, there is no option to choose c/c++ project.

I also, tried the [suggested solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21201696/using-eclipse-cdt), but the problem still occurs

I'm using mac OS X Yosemite.

Is there something I'm missing?

Thanks

Comment: What Xcode has to do with Eclipse?

Comment: Have you already considered downloading eclipse specifically for C/C++: http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-cc-developers/lunasr2?

Comment: @Eugene Sh, as specified by the help menu in eclipse, in "Before you begin" section, that it require toolchain and mac users can use the one provided by Xcode: "The CDT supports the Apple GNU toolchain that is included in with the Xcode IDE. It can be downloaded from the Apple's developer site, http://developer.apple.com"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved when I reinstall CDT with all relative packages, i.e. I installed everything that starts with C/C++.

Answer (score 0):

You might have Java 6 installed.

Check the version and update to Java 7 at least.

Eclipse site says "A Java 7 JRE/JDK is required" for Eclipse Mars(4.5).

Comment: Thanks LiMar, but I'm using Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2) which support Java 6. Why do you think that updating the java will solve the problem?

Comment: The same requirement applies to Luna. Look here: https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse/Installation#Eclipse_4.4_.28Luna.29 Be sure to update the JDK.

Comment: I updated the Java JDK to version 7, but still I'm not able to create a c project